# How to animate child control by event in the parent control? - Reusable way

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, controls

I have a DockPanel and a Button inside it. I want to animate (for example, fade in/out) the button by event (for example, mouse hovering) in the dock panel.

**EDIT**

Well, I found the solution only for nontemplated/nonstyled case (see below). How to bring it to reusable way?

```xml
<DockPanel>
  <Button> 
    Name="aaa"
  </Button>

  <DockPanel.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DockPanel.MouseEnter">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation 
            Duration="0:0:0.100" 
            To="1" 
            Storyboard.TargetName="aaa"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DockPanel.MouseLeave">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation 
            Duration="0:0:0.100" 
            To="0" 
            Storyboard.TargetName="aaa"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>    
  </DockPanel.Triggers>

</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, the only idea I have is to wrap the `Controls` you want to show in a `ContentControl`. Then you may only need to create a template for the `ContentControl`.

**EDIT**

`ContentPresenter` => `ContentControl`

**EDIT2**

According to the edit of the **TO**:

If you would like to take an approach with events, which is a proper but IMHO less elegant approach, you would have to implement these methods in the code behind of your view. e.g.

```
private void OnMouseOver(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  var control = sender as Control; // perhaps you could cast to another base class
  if (control == null)
    return;
  // implement the behavior you like
  // ...
}
```

The biggest problem, and IMHO the reason why is less elegant, you have to add and remove the method to each `Control` which is added to the DockPanel in code behind.

If you're not familiar with templating it may be the better solution for you.

Comment: I dont think this is valid design because if you apply this style to all controls inside dockpanel will fadein and fade out at the same time and if this what you want then you are better off targeting the dockpanel

Comment: @mhashim: Ok, why is that so? I'm sorry, but without any valid arguments, it's pretty to difficult to discuss and improve my suggestion.

Comment: @mhashim: Hmm, good point. But I don't see another possibility since I cannot apply a `ContentTemplate` (or sth. comparable) to the `DockPanel`.

Comment: @mhashim: I thought about your point. I think, it will work. Since every added `Control` will be encapsulated in its own instance of a `ContentControl` I don't see, why they should share the same animation. Unfortunately, I cannot verify it due to lack of time.

Comment: And if without templating - just animate a child control by event in the parent control? I fixed the question.

Comment: Thanks, but code behind is not a desirable way for me now. So, I can receive a templeted/styled way - any reusable way in XAML only. I edited the question by adding some markup to obtain animation that I want. How to bring it to reusable way? Can you provide me some code example please?

Comment: @user808128 I'm sorry, but since you wanted to have some animations on the items, your approach would only work, if you don't add dynamically random items to the dock panel. But in that case you wouldn't need a `DockPanel`. So back to the approach with the `ContentControl` as wrapper for each control you want to add to the `DockPanel`.

Comment: I did as you say but with using UserControl and DataTemplate (I'm used to). But how to point the ContentPresenter to use a specific ContentControl? Is it possible without any data contexts and data templates?

Comment: @user808128 Please show me the essential part of the code of your `UserControl`. Your approach should be pretty easy to use. Just create a property e.g. `Content` and bind the internal `ContentPresenter` to it.